# get value from specific tag as created c#

Tags: get, controls, tagname

How to get the value inside de control aspx?

sample.

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" tag="value_test2"
        runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

I would like to get the value from tag="...".

Answer (score 1):

```
var value = TextBox1.Attributes["tag"].Value
```